# Why do I get InvalidCastException when I open then close the Menu on my Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.7.2

When I create a new WPF Application in NET Framework 4.7.2 add a Menu to the MainWindow I get the `InvalidCastException` whenever you click on the menu and then click away from the menu to close it.

I can ignore this exception when it is thrown from `PresentationFramework.dll` and all is well I am just interested as to whether this is a NET Framework issue or something I have got wrong?

Entire solution can be found here https://github.com/glrad/InvalidCastException

App.xaml.cs

```cs
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var view = new MainWindow();
    MainWindow = view;
    view.Show();
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="MyApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="GASGC3" Height="800" Width="1000">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu Grid.Row="0">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="Options" InputGestureText="Ctrl+O"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Exit" InputGestureText="Alt+F4" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Help">
                <MenuItem Header="About" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Exception thrown:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Hashtable' to type 'System.String'.'

Comment: You can enable break when thrown `System.InvalidCastException` in Exception settings to check what causes this problem

Comment: We can't help you unless you show complete code. See [mcve].

Comment: I can get it to break on this exception but am at a loss as to why it is being raised, the entire exception is `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)`

Comment: @BenBancroft I've tried to run your code and didn't find any problems/exceptions, except the thing, that `MainWindow` runs twice (because you override `OnStartup` method)

Comment: Same as Pavel, are you missing code here? I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @BenBancroft You can check the call stack to see what causes an exception

Comment: Doesn't it occur in your code (e.g. Options_Click or something)? Try to put a break point there.

Comment: Edited to include link to solution repo, @PavelAnikhouski I had removed the StartupUri from the App.xaml file, hnece why yours was showing two MainWindows

Comment: @BenBancroft I see the same, no errors/exceptions. Try to cleanup and reload the project and VS

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski have you changed your exception settings to break on all CLR exceptions, I didn't see this until I enabled them all?

Comment: @BenBancroft There is no exceptions in debug output, it doesn't really what you've enabled in settings to throw in this case

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski must just be me then but I don't understand why I am seeing these exceptions from what it basically just an empty WPF project...

Comment: I you enable breaking on all CLR exceptions, Visual Studio will show you internal exceptions that have been caught and would otherwise not bubble up to the user.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes so you think that these exceptions are normal and should just be ignored? I am happy to untick the box it just didn't seem right to me but I have a paranoia about watching for exceptions when working with WPF bindings.

Comment: That's correct. In winforms these internal exceptions happen very often. You should enable breaking on all CLR exception only when you are tracking hard to find bugs. Usually you even set a breakpoint, start the app with this CLR exceptions off (to avoid running into them all the time), then, when the breakpoint is hit, check this option and continue to test only specific code. Note, this shows handled exceptions, so don't worry about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you see this exception because you have changed the Exception Settings in Visual Studio and enabled CLR exceptions.

If you check *Break when thrown: Common Language Runtime Exceptions*, then you will see exceptions that are caught and would otherwise never bubble up to the user. These exceptions are normal.

You should enable breaking on CLR exceptions only when you are tracking hard to find bugs. Usually you even set a breakpoint, start the app with CLR exceptions off (to avoid running into them all the time), then, when the breakpoint is hit, check this option and continue to test only specific code. Usually you do this, if you want to see exceptions that you have handled and swallowed silently in a try-catch statement.

Note, this shows handled exceptions, so don't worry about them.

Comment: I will accept this as this issue doesn't affect my application from successfully executing but I would love to know the underlying reason for this exception, even it is being handled internally.